# UITextField inside UITableView cell doesn't respond

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, uitextfield, ios7.1

I have a UITextField inside a UIView B, B is inside UITableView.

B is a custom UITableView from xib.

The problem is that the UITextField doesn't respond and the user can't enter text , in ios 7 and lower it was working fine.

Any ideas?

Comment: Make sure you `userInteractionEnabled = YES` on the cell and its content view.

Comment: buttons in the same view work and respond to events

Comment: ok, so after some test when you add the textfield by code all works fine, the problem is only when using a uitextfield inside a custom xib, any ideas?

Comment: Even we are facing a similar issue. Our text field is added through code only. It worked fine in iOS 7.0 and lower  but now we are facing issue in iOS 7.1.

Comment: Did u subclass uitextfield?

Answer (score 1):

so the problem was that our uitextfield was a subclass of uitextfieldn, and in the function willmovetowindow we didn't called [super willmovetowi...] in ios < 7.1 it worked fine, in ios 7.1 the hierarchy of the view changed and that caused a problem...